# Move all files not already in a directory into a self named directory?

Tags: linux, bash

This bash command will move all files that are not already in a directory into a new self-named folder.

```
ll | grep ^- | awk -F"." '{print $2 "." $3}' | awk -F":" '{print $2}' | awk '{$1=""; print $0}' | cut -c2- | awk -F"." '{print "mkdir ""$1"";mv ""$1"."$2"" ""$1"""}' > tmp;source tmp
```

Comment: mmh where is the question?

Comment: [Read here: Why you should not parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: If the question would be: "What is the worst possible solution to achieve the goal", then this would be very close.

Comment: Using `grep` and `cut` while using `awk`?? piping through 4 `awk` processes?? this is really `awk`ward.

Comment: What is the problem or question? Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question."*

Answer (score 1):

To move all *files* in the current directory into directories named after the base part of the filename:

```
for f in *
do 
  [ -f "$f" -o -d "${f%.*}" ] || continue
  mkdir "${f%.*}" && mv "$f" "${f%.*}"
done
```

This skips any entries in the current directory that are not `-f` files; it also skips any entries that already have directories named for them. It then creates the directory (named by stripping "period followed by anything" off of the filename) and if that's successful, moves the file into that directory.

Comment: no, but neither will the example code, as it's splitting the filenames based on periods.